# Video appears pixelated only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I am building a tab section which holds videos. The tabs or the video containers are of 640*360 dimensions. The video resolution is 1920*1080. The video appears a bit blurred on Chrome, especially the text. Video works fine when you go full screen.

I tried reducing the resolution to 1280*720. Although it fixes the pixelation when the video is played in the tab itself but quality is degraded on going full screen.

`<video class="inlineVideo" controls="controls" id="videoA">
 <source src="Img/Banner/private/SROC_BIS_1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>`

Is there any way to fix this for Chrome? The video appears fine on other browsers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show an example please. I mean working example with a playable video. Or read this - http://webz.ro/blurry-html5-video/

Comment: Thanks, I will try correcting the size.